# 99 Dodge ram No power at all

Tags: electrical, battery, dodge, wiring, ram

I have a 1999 Dodge Ram 1500 with Magnum engine. I lost the key so a friend hotwired it at the steering column. It worked fine until at some point when starting it via wires he crossed 2 wires now theres no power at all to the truck.. also it now sparks when i try to jump it off  Someone please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It sounds like either some fuses got fried or something in the wiring has melted and is now shorted. Whatever the issue is, it doesn't sound good.